# How do I configure the Chain ID of a new EOS Chain?

Tags: nodeos

I'm trying to create two EOS chains - I am under the impression that each chain should have a unique `chain_id`, but when I start them, they both come up with the same `chain_id` (checked via `cleos get info`)

I checked the config.ini and didn't see anything that indicated how to do it. How do I set the Chain ID to something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chain_id` is a hash of the fields in `genesis.json`. Change any field to get a different id.